# One newline equals two newlines in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, newlines

So while i was testing a python program i have been working on i noticed that `echo -e "\n"` and `printf "\n"` according to the `if` statement in bash.

Even though `echo -e "\n"` prints two newlines (it appends one by default) and printf only prints one.

```
if [ "$(echo -e "\n")" == "$(printf "\n")" ]
then
    echo 1
fi
```

and

```
if [ $(echo -e "\n") -eq $(printf "\n") ]
then
    echo 1
fi
```

both outputs 1 in bash. I have also noticed that assigning the outputs to an variable only outputs a single newline for both `echo -e "\n"` and `printf "\n"`,

```
A=$(echo -e "\n")
B=$(printf "\n")

echo $A # outputs a single newline
echo $B # also outputs a single newline
```

so i am thinking that `echo` might output the newline differently with fx. stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newlines are deleted by the command substitution `$()`. The manpage of bash says:

> *Command substitution* allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing *command* in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.  The command substitution $(cat *file*) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< *file*).

Comment: @JavadSM BTW, even if `$( )` didn't remove the newlines, if it's unquoted the shell will treat those newlines as whitespace and ignore them. Thus, `[ $(echo -e "\n") -eq $(printf "\n") ]` parses down to the equivalent of `[ -eq ]`, which is true because "-eq" is not the null string. `[ $(echo -e "\n") -ne $(printf "\n") ]` and `[ $(echo -e "\n") wibble $(printf "\n") ]` will give the same result for the same reason. Moral: use double-quotes around pretty much all command and variable expansions to avoid parsing weirdness.